# Using SUMIF with INDIRECT

Tags: excel-formula

Values are in another sheet which is named as cell value"A3"

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT(" ' "&A3&" '$B:$B"),D$2,INDIRECT(" ' "&A3&" '!$M:$M"))
```

do you see anything wrong with this formula ?

doesn't work `#REF!` is the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By enclosing A3 in ampersands you are referencing cell A3 in the current sheet. What you want is:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'A3'!$B:$B"),D$2,INDIRECT("'A3'!$M:$M"))
```

On second look, if you are intending to reference a sheet that is named what you have in cell A3 then you don't need the apostrophes around the cell reference:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT(A3&"!$B:$B"),D$2,INDIRECT(A3&"!$M:$M"))
```

Comment: Thanks that works =SUMIF(INDIRECT(A3&"!$B:$B"),D$2,INDIRECT(A3&"!$M:$M"))